# MPI Receive and Send for Eigen compressed sparse matrix

Tags: c++, mpi, sparse-matrix, eigen, eigen3

What is the best (fastest) way to send and receive sparse matrix that is defined using Eigen library?

Currently, I am creating a value, row and column vector (from a pre-defined sparse matrix) using only the nonzero elements and sending/receiving these 3 vectors one by one. These vectors are simple std::vector

```
if (0 == myrank) {
    Sz.insert(0,0) = 0.5;       Sz.insert(1,1) = -0.5;

    //------ preparing to send ----------
    shape[0] = Sz.rows();
    shape[1] = Sz.cols();
    int size=Sz.nonZeros();
    val.resize(size); inner.resize(size); outer.resize(size);
    cout << "val-size = "<< val.size() << endl;
    int counter=0;
    for (int k=0; k<Sz.outerSize(); ++k) {
        for (CrsMatrixType::InnerIterator it(Sz,k); it; ++it)  {
            val[counter]=it.value();
            inner[counter]=it.col();
            outer[counter]=it.row();
            counter++;
        }
    }
    assert(counter==size);
    MPI_Send(&shape[0],2,MPI_INT,1, 100, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Send(&size,1,MPI_INT,1, 101, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Send(&val[0],size,MPI_DOUBLE,1, 102, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Send(&inner[0],size,MPI_INT,1, 103, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Send(&outer[0],size,MPI_INT,1, 104, MPI_COMM_WORLD);


}
```

Later, I receive them using

```
if (1 == myrank) {

    //------ preparing to receive ----------
    shape.resize(2);
    int size;
    MPI_Recv(&shape[0],2,MPI_INT,0, 100, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    MPI_Recv(&size,1,MPI_INT,0, 101, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

    val.resize(size); inner.resize(size); outer.resize(size);
    MPI_Recv(&val[0],size,MPI_DOUBLE,0, 102, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    MPI_Recv(&inner[0],size,MPI_INT,0, 103, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    MPI_Recv(&outer[0],size,MPI_INT,0, 104, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);


    Sz.resize(shape[0],shape[1]);
    Sz.reserve(size); // allocate room for nonzero elements only.
    for (int k=0; k<Sz.outerSize(); ++k) {
        Sz.coeffRef(inner[k],outer[k]) = val[k];
    }

    cout << "my RANK " << myrank << endl;
    cout << Sz << endl;
}
```

and add them to the sparse matrix of rank 1.

Is there any better way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: First, you should send `shape` and `size` in one shot. Then you can create a `struct` with two `MPI_INT` and one `MPI_ DOUBLE` that describes an element of the matrix, allocate and fill it, build a derived datatype for that, and the send `size` elements in one shot.

Comment: Thanks! :D 
I went with @chtz comment below. It avoids making temporaries and directly fill the matrix in rank 1.

Answer (score 3):

I generally suggest to use the compressed form to transfer sparse matrices. And there is no need to copy values into temporary `std::vector`s.

```
void sendSparseEigen(const Ref<const SparseMatrix<double>,StandardCompressedFormat>& mat) {
    int rows=mat.rows, cols=mat.cols, nnz=mat.nonZeros();
    assert(rows==mat.innerSize() && cols==mat.outerSize());
    assert(mat.outerIndexPtr()[cols]==nnz);
    int shape[3] = {rows, cols, nnz};
    MPI_Send(shape              ,3   ,MPI_INT,   1, 100, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Send(mat.valuePtr()     ,nnz ,MPI_DOUBLE,1, 101, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Send(mat.innerIndexPtr(),nnz ,MPI_INT,   1, 102, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Send(mat.outerIndexPtr(),cols,MPI_INT,   1, 103, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}

void receiveSparseEigen(SparseMatrix<double> &out){
    int shape[3];
    MPI_Recv(shape,3,MPI_INT,0, 100, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    int rows=shape[0], cols=shape[1], nnz=shape[2];
    out.resize(rows, cols);
    out.reserve(nnz);
    MPI_Recv(out.valuePtr(),  nnz, MPI_DOUBLE,0, 101, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    MPI_Recv(out.innerIndexPtr(),nnz, MPI_INT,0, 102, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    MPI_Recv(out.outerIndexPtr(),cols,MPI_INT,0, 103, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    out.outerIndexPtr()[cols] = nnz;
}
```

Disclaimer: I'm no MPI expert, I copied all MPI related code from your example -- obviously you should handle all possible errors generated by MPI somehow. And the code above is untested.

Comment: Works like charm, although I have not test the speed/memory explicitly. It is clear that your solution avoids creating temporary that saves memory and redundant operations. Thanks!

One more thing, in future, if someone else is using this solution, make sure to compress the sparse matrix before you pass. 
mat.makeCompressed();

Comment: True, you could actually remove the `StandardCompressedFormat` flag from the `Ref` and just `assert(mat.isCompressed());` Or pass a non-const `SparseMatrix&` and call `makeCompressed()` inside the first function.